# Добавление страниц на  сайта

Tags: html

Я на сайте когда создаю страницу новую и там нет функции добавки статей. Там должно быть написано (добавить статью) на страницу, которую я создаю. Можно редактировать только html и визуально я не знаю кода html, чтоб добавить возможность добавки статей отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял из этого довольно запутанного вопроса, у вас сайт на uCoz и при добавлении новой страницы, которую можно редактировать визуально и html.Хм.

С помощью html вы не сможете добавить такую функцию, так как это язык разметки.
Да и при создании просто страницы у ucoz нет такой функции, если только не включить php и написать функцию.